# Conversion from string "ual" to type 'Double' is not valid

Tags: vb.net

get error in this line

Else

```
        Hitung = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(Rd.GetString(0), 3) + 1
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxrsO.png

Comment: Your string is letters, a double is a number; you can't convert letters to a number.

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Comment: It would probably help a lot if you told us exactly where your getting that error

Comment: That is a great deal of code to show what appears to be an error on a single line.

Comment: sorry, this is my first time ask a question in this web sorry

Answer (score 0):

What database are you using that required Odbc rather than its own provider?

I would assume that the labels are empty to begin with so there is not need to set the `.Text` to `""`.

The `Call` keyword is no longer necessary.

Get rid of the `Koneksi` method and the declarations of `Cmd` and `Rd`. Database objects should be created and disposed in the method where they are used. The language provides `Using...End Using` blocks that takes care of this for us even if there is an error.

Do not update the user interface (fill a combo box, labels etc.) while the connection is open. If you use a `DataTable`, the reader (which requires an open connection) can fill it and the connection can be closed.

Do not concatenate strings to build sql statements. Always use parameters. See the
`ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged` event.

Finally, in the last method I see your problem in the `NomorOtomatic` method. Option Strict would help you. See my comment.

```
Hitung = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(Rd.GetString(0), 3) + 1
```

The old vb6 `Right` method returns a `String`. You can't add one to String. The compiler is attempting to convert `Right(Rd.GetString(0), 3)` to a `Double` so it can perform the addition. Apparently what is retured is `"ual"` which cannot be converted to a number.

I have replaced the `Right` method with the .net `Substring` method. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-5.0

I have added a `.TryParse` to check if there is a valid number and exited gracefully if the parse fails.

```
Private ConStr As String = "Your connection string"

Dim tgljualMySQL As String

Sub kondisiawal()
    lbltanggal.Text = Today
    lbladmin.Text = FormMenuUtama.STLabel4.Text
    TextBox3.Enabled = False
    Label12.Text = "0"
    munculkodepelanggan()
    NomorOtomatis()
    BuatKolom()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    lbljam.Text = TimeOfDay.ToString
End Sub

Private Sub Formtransjual_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    kondisiawal()
End Sub

Sub munculkodepelanggan()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using Conn As New OdbcConnection(ConStr),
            Cmd As New OdbcCommand("select * from tbl_pelanggan", Conn)
        Conn.Open()
        Using Rd = Cmd.ExecuteReader
            dt.Load(Rd)
        End Using
    End Using
    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(row(0))
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using Conn As New OdbcConnection(ConStr),
            Cmd As New OdbcCommand("select * from tbl_pelanggan where kodepelanggan = ?;", Conn)
        Cmd.Parameters.Add("@ComboText", OdbcType.NVarChar, 50).Value = ComboBox1.Text
        Conn.Open()
        Using Rd = Cmd.ExecuteReader
            dt.Load(Rd)
        End Using
    End Using
    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        lblnamaplg.Text = dt(0)("namapelanggan")
        lblalamat.Text = dt(0)("alamatpelanggan")
        lbltelepon.Text = dt(0)("telppelanggan")
    End If
End Sub

Sub NomorOtomatis()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using Conn As New OdbcConnection(ConStr),
            Cmd = New OdbcCommand("Select * from tbl_jual where nojual in(select max(nojual) from tbl_jual)", Conn)
        Conn.Open()
        Using Rd = Cmd.ExecuteReader
            dt.Load(Rd)
        End Using
    End Using
    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Dim StrHitung = dt(0)(0).ToString
        Dim Hitung As Integer
        If Not Integer.TryParse(StrHitung.Substring(StrHitung.Length - 3), Hitung) Then
            MessageBox.Show($"Database returned {StrHitung}. The right 3 characters cannot be converted to a number")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        TextBox1.Text = "ADM" & (Hitung + 1)
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = "ADM001"
    End If
End Sub
```

BTW, what are you going to do when your numbers are above 999?

Comment: @RevaDiva You have included the `If Not Integer.TryParse` code? If so, you shouldn't get any error; just the message box. If there is incorrect data in your database then you can't use this method. This is a terrible way to get a primary key. Let the database do an auto-number field to produce the PK.